# pin two elements in Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using CoordinatoLayout to try to achieve something like this:

This is my initial view

[image: initial view]

Scrolled up

[image: scrolled]

I am using Coordinator layout this way but I am a bit confused about it, ¿is it the right way to  achieve it? I have tried different ways but I only get one textview pinned on top.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:titleEnabled="false">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">


                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/rv_pending_request_list"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_double_padding"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/app_double_padding" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_double_padding"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/app_double_padding">

                    <com.vipera.onepay.ui.component.custom.CustomTextViewRegular
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:text="@string/payment_request_pending_request_text"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_content_10" />


                    <com.vipera.onepay.ui.component.custom.CustomButtonLight
                        style="@style/ButtonSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_rounded_gradient"
                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/payment_request_small_btn_side_small_padding"
                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/payment_request_small_btn_side_small_padding"
                        android:text="@string/payment_request_movements_btn"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_content_10" />

                </RelativeLayout>


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/colorAccent">

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_double_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_double_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/app_double_padding">


                <com.vipera.onepay.ui.component.custom.CustomTextViewRegular
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:text="@string/payment_request_rejected_request_text"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_content_10" />

            </RelativeLayout>



        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">




            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_rejected_request_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/app_double_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/app_double_padding" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Can somebody explain how to get this? Thanks in advance